# How do I output the users name inside a custom field within the account object using visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, apex-email-service

I currently have tired {!relatedTo.Trainer__c} however that gets me the users's ID. I have also tried  but that gets me a link to the users profile.

This email is going to clients so it cannot be a link to the users salesforce profile.

Any thoughts? Are there .tags I can use within {!relatedTo.xxx} so it gets the users name not their ID?

The trouble im running into is that it is a custom field that references the contact object from the account object so i cannot call $User.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a child relationship (Account a child of User in this case) then you should be able to have something like `{!relatedTo.Trainer__r.Name}`

Essentially, the syntax is `{AccountObject.RelationshipName__r.UserField}`

Comment: Thanks! I created a function field in account that references it. i think Trainer__r would work as well.